# Titlebar buttons dissapear

Tags: 20.04, titlebar, window-buttons

Why does the titlebar button disappear when I maximize the window? But when not maximized the titlebar buttons are visible. How to solve this problem? Sorry for my english

[Maximize window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWd4f.png)

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: i use kubuntu 20.04 version